# Linux: disable wtmp/utmp, sshd ip logging and any mentions of ip that does remote access

Tags: linux, security

Any ideas how to do all above?
I've disabled LOG_OK_LOGINS and SYSLOG_SU_ENAB in login.defs, but still don't know how to do everything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by @quanta, it is impossible to disable wtmp/utmp. But it is possible there's a dirty hack:

```
rm /var/log/wtmp && ln -s /dev/null /var/log/wtmp
```

So far so good, make sure logrotate won't remove it though.

Answer (score 3):

According to [man wtmp](http://linux.die.net/man/5/wtmp), you cannot disable utmp on Linux:

> Unlike  various  other systems, where utmp logging can be disabled by
>   removing the file, utmp must always exist on Linux.  If you want to
>   disable who(1) then do not make utmp world readable.

About the sshd ip logging, you can comment the line begin with `auth, authpriv` facility in `/etc/syslog.conf`:

```
#authpriv.*                      /var/log/secure
```

and restart the syslog daemon:

```
# /etc/init.d/syslog start
Starting system logger:                                    [  OK  ]
Starting kernel logger:                                    [  OK  ]
```

PS: Could you please tell us the reason you want to do that?

Comment: i did a dirty hack: rm /var/log/wtmp && ln -s /dev/null /var/log/wtmp. seems to be working

Comment: why i need that: total anonimization of people logging into the server

Comment: Anonymization? What do you mean?

Comment: in case if server will be hacked attacker shouldn't find out where did i login from

Comment: thats a totally valid point. e.g. the darkleech toolkit, that infects apache >= 2.2.2, checks utmp in order to avoid showing malicious iframes to the admin, so it goes unnoticed.

Comment: @Daniel your `ln -s /dev/null` is wonderful, thank you. Please add it as an answer so I can upvote it :D